# Synonymize [laravel-backpack] and [backpack-for-laravel]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

These two: [laravel-backpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel-backpack) and [backpack-for-laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/backpack-for-laravel) are clearly for the same thing.

They should be made one and the same, if only to prevent users to tag all their questions with **both** tags. :(

My preference would be that [backpack-for-laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/backpack-for-laravel) be the synonym of [laravel-backpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel-backpack), but for some reason the former seems to be about 6 times more popular than the latter.

[image]

Comment: "*for some reason the former seems to be about 6 times more popular than the latter.*" seems like the official name (at least what the site gives) is "Backpack for Laravel", so that might be why it's more popular. But I agree that "laravel-backpack" is probably better for a tag name.

Comment: That would be awesome! I also think “Backpack-for-laravel” would be better.

Comment: I went with [laravel-backpack], to keep with the existing subtags for laravel. Tags merged.